# Visual studio project, how to check if project is VB or C#

Tags: visual-studio-project

I'd like to create a targets file that is compatible with C# and VB projects, unfortunately it needs knowledge of the project language.

I could just make one file for each language, but it would be cleaner if I could just use one file, and have a condition that checks which language we need.

Is there a way of doing this?

I was hoping for something like this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Language)"' == 'C#'">
```

or

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(ProjectFile).Extension' == 'csproj'">
```

I've tried searching, but there is a lot of noise for these search terms.  I've tried many variations on the following terms with no luck.

- msbuild project check language
- msbuild project condition if vb or c#
- csproj check language

If we get a good answer, hopefully the next person will find this a lot easier to find an answer for.

Comment: Could maybe checking for the specific `<import />` work? There should be either `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />` or `<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />` imported.

Comment: @Filburt how do you check for an import?

Comment: Still trying to figure that out myself.

Comment: Interesting one. Looks like you've found the Language property (I see it in output when using /v:diag),  Running MSBuild with /pp:C:/out.txt  (see -preprocess[:file]) on an ASP.NET C# project shows it coming down from  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" /> in Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets. I see it used like     <IsCSharpOrVbProject Condition="'$(Language)'=='C#' or '$(Language)'=='VB'">true</IsCSharpOrVbProject> in  Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets. So it looks like you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I successfully used "**MSBuildProjectExtension**" inside **Directory.Build.props**, as in the following example:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)'=='.csproj'">
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)'=='.vbproj'">
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```